# REGEX to get the elements from the image filename

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse a set of filenames with the next pattern:

**A0001L+23.20K+01-Red.JPG**

Into the followed elements:

- Get the first Number -> 0001
- Get the L value -> 23.20 (Could be positive or negative number)
- Get the K value -> 01 (Could be positive or negative number)
- Get the color -> Red

I'm using the the approach of REGEX groups using the next pattern:

```
IMAGE_PATTERN = "[A-Z](\\d\\d\\d\\d)[A-Z][-|\\+](\\d\\d\\.\\d\\d)[A-Z][-|\\+](\\d\\d)-([A-Za-z]+)(\\.[A-Za-z]+)";
```

But is not working correctly, is the IMAGE_PATTERN, set it right?

Comment: The new one you just added [seems to work fine](https://regex101.com/r/cvuEfR/1) to me. You should just replace `[-|\\+]` with `[-+]` and you can also use `\\d{4}` to match four digits.

Comment: If the `L` and `K` values are positive or negative, don't you want to capture the sign as well?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested below pattern and it works:

```
[a-zA-Z]([0-9]{4})L\+([0-9\.]+)K([+\-][0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z]+)
```

You can modify it to suit your needs.

You may check out the below link

[Regex101Link](https://regex101.com/r/TTRDf8/1)

Comment: Didn't work for me. In fact, the pattern in the question itself is correct.

Comment: @HarshalParekh Perhaps it didn't work for you because you used `matches()`, when you should be using `find()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are after this, includes fetching +/- as well

```
[a-zA-Z](\d{4})[A-Z]([+\-]\d{2}\.\d{2})K([+\-][0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z]+)
```

[Regex Test Link](https://regex101.com/r/cvuEfR/3)

[image]